# test python socket server by nc or telnet

Tags: python, sockets, telnet, netcat

I have a simple socket server by python

```
#!/usr/bin/python3           # This is server.py file
import socket                                         

# create a socket object
serversocket = socket.socket(
            socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

# get local machine name
host = socket.gethostname()                           

port = 2115                                           

# bind to the port
serversocket.bind((host, port))                                  

# queue up to 5 requests
serversocket.listen(5)                                           

while True:
    # establish a connection
    clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()      

    print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))

    msg = serversocket.recv(1024)
    print (msg.decode('ascii'))
    clientsocket.close()
```

I want to test this server by nc or telnet for example

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 2115
```

but causes error
but when i try to connect by another socket program written in python. works well

Comment: What error does it give?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `host = socket.gethostname()`, your `host` is assigned to something like `"MacBookPro.local"`. Then you bind your server to it at `serversocket.bind((host, port))`. Thus your listening socket isn't bound to `127.0.0.1`, so the connection attempt from telnet gets refused.

Instead, try `serversocket.bind('', port)` and re-run your server. This time, it should accept the telnet connection.